# the request class in urllib module is not there

Tags: python, urllib

Im trying to play around with the urllib on python 3.6.7, but my urllib does not contain the following classes:

error, parse, request, response

I've tried to use urllib3 but the request class there does not contain the urlopen() method

```
>>> import urllib
>>> dir(urllib)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

```
>>> dir(urllib3)
['HTTPConnectionPool', 'HTTPResponse', 'HTTPSConnectionPool', 'PoolManager', 'ProxyManager', 'Retry', 'Timeout', '__all__', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__license__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_collections', 'absolute_import', 'add_stderr_logger', 'connection', 'connection_from_url', 'connectionpool', 'disable_warnings', 'encode_multipart_formdata', 'exceptions', 'fields', 'filepost', 'get_host', 'logging', 'make_headers', 'packages', 'poolmanager', 'proxy_from_url', 'request', 'response', 'util', 'warnings']
```

Comment: maybe it is not python 3?

Comment: And if you `import urllib.request`, for example?

Comment: It is python 3, is there a way to reinstall only the urllib maybe that will solve my problem